# Laravel. OAuth facebook authentication. Check if user logged out from facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, laravel

I want to know if there is way to check if user logged out from facebook? Or I need every time to do like:

```
 $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Suscribe to the `authResponseChange` event. Then you can know when the user login/logout.

Here is a javascript example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        //User login
    }
    else
        //User logout
    });
}
```

This example is in Javascript but i'm sure you can do the same in PHP. Just check the Facebook API documentation.